# How can I set multiple browser width media queries for my website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am attempting to change to top margin on a div according to the browser width.. using one query along with the main css worked but when I added another set of screen widths/correlating styles they did not respond. What is the best way to have multiple device widths say if I wanted to have 4 or 5 different margin tops as the screen adjusts.

the code below is an example of what I tried and I am not too sure what I am doing wrong... All help is greatly appreciated.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 410px){
.inner-cont{margin-top:130px;}}

@media screen and (min-width:411px) and(max-width: 1000px){
.inner-cont{margin-top:50px;}}
```

I am new to this but am learning alot and am very appreciative to all on this site for all the help. Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a space here, and thus your `media` query fails

```
and(max-width: 1000px)
 --^--
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UFuze/) *(Resize the fiddle window to see the effect)*

Also, am not having the markup, so if you are trying to apply `margin-top:130px;` on an `inline` element, it will simply fail, also, inheritance matters, order of the media query matters too, but as far as the question goes with the provided code, only issue I can see was the missing space..

Comment: 1+ Nice catch - I didn't even see that!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `only` keyword but 
 [**your media-query works,  see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNQeF/1/)

for eg

```
 @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

[**see examples here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNQeF/)  (*change browser width to understand*)

Comment: so multiple of those for all the device widths I want and I will be set?

Comment: `only` keywords is used so that IE8 < will skip that piece of CSS, it has nothing to do with *not working*

Comment: @user3145782 : it works...see the edited link in answer

Comment: @user3145782 I answered

Comment: @NoobEditor lol thank you and a very happy new year to you too :)